# Accents in the title and description tags

Tags: html, seo

In some languages we use accents and other special characters like ç... For instance to write à we use `&aacute;` When I write words with accents in the title and description meta tags, alt in the img and title in links what should I use?:

- no accents: a
- normal accents: à
- the special character: `&aacute;`

I should think about what is correct with html and what is more useful for search engines and seo.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` section of you HTML page, you can add:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

to specify a characters set. If your special characters are encoded with UTF-8 (in this case), you are safe.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question.

Comment: Seems or are you sure? Browsers make an assumption on the character set used in html document and if characters are not encoded properly, they won't be displayed properly and that includes titles and meta tags.

Comment: This seems to be answering the question "How can I use literal non-ASCII characters?" not "Which of transliteration, literal non-ASCII characters or character references should I use?"

Comment: What is the original question again? Did you read it? Does the title mention meta tags or not? Or are you answering your own idea of the question? You should delete your answer and undo your -1... Really, for the spirit of SO...

Comment: It mentions meta tags, but not in the context of how to set the character encoding of the document. It's asking about the relative merits of transliteration, literal non-ASCII characters and character references and uses meta tags as an example of one place they might be used.

Comment: I, of course use utf-8. I am not sure if I understand your answer, do you mean that if I use utf-8 I can use any of the 3 options I suggest?  This is not right in the body, why do you think I can use any one in the title meta tag?

Comment: @Nrc Yes and no. Body and meta tags a treated differently. You can use accentuated characters in meta tag attribute values, but not within<p>...</p> (for example).

Answer (score -1):

They are all correct HTML.

Only two are correct *whatever human language* (e.g. French) you are writing in.

Search engines shouldn't care about the difference between a literal and a character reference.

Comment: All are correct, then only two are correct? What are you talking about dude? Sure people can encode '&aacute;' characters, but that's a lot of extra work in titles and meta-tags. You've missed the point !!!

Comment: @JVerstry — All are correct HTML. Only two are correct French or whatever.

Comment: Do you mean that I can write in French: différents or diff&eacute;rents in the title and description meta tags, alt in the img and title in links,  and this will not affect search engines?

Comment: @Nrc — It shouldn't make any difference. (Search engines, however, don't publish their algorithms and may have bugs)